# cyclic convolution: still have problems in understanding it correctly

Tags: fft, fast-convolution

[image: convolution]

I have the following scenario where there are 9 input boxes $S_{m\prime}$ and each box contain $L$ samples.

I transfer the input samples of $S_{m\prime}$ to $G_m$ by multiplying and summing each sample of $S_{m\prime}$ and $T_{m,m\prime}$ to get the $G_m$.

$$G_m\left(\hat{\mathrm{k}}\right)=\sum_{m\prime}T_{m,m\prime}\left(\hat{\mathrm{k}}\right)S_m\prime\left(\hat{\mathrm{k}}\right)$$

First question: How do I do it with fast-convolution?

My idea is, for m=0

```
G_m = ifft(fft(T_m_m').*fft(S_m'), L)
```

Is it correct to take first `L` samples of `G_m`?

Second question: What happens if I pad the samples with zeros to get size of fft to `2^nextpow2()`?

I am using mkl library to perform forward and inverse Fourier transformation.

Comment: Oh where oh where is @MarcusMuller who should have been be the first to comment on this question?

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve the fast-convolution? Still not so clear for me...

Comment: What you have written is _not_ a convolution at all, and thus it is futile to hope for a fast convolution method to solve the problem.

Comment: Sir, its actually a convolution problem and this algorithm is a part of Fast Multi-pole Method.